# .NET MAUI Blazor Not Showing Blazor Views on iOS Simulator

Tags: .net, xaml, blazor, maui

I have tried on a physical device and Mac Catalyst and it works great, it just shows nothing on the simulators which is a bit of an inconvenience. Anyone else running into the same issue?

Update: I have found it to be a bug on the newest VS and Xcode. If I start a new Blazor MAUI project and run the app in a simulator it results in the same.

[image]

```
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="#6C91E6"
                                   StatusBarStyle="LightContent"></toolkit:StatusBarBehavior>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app"
                           ComponentType="{x:Type test:Login}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Xcode 14.2 is being working on and it's not supported yet. You can try downgrading back to Xcode 14.1 and run the app on an iOS16.1 device. (Go to [downloads page](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin.html?path=%2Fdownload%2Fall%2F&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&rv=0) in the Apple Developer Portal, sign in with your apple developer account, select Xcode14.1 to download and install). Then you can open Xcode, go to Preferences > Location > Command Line Tools, and make sure to select version 14.1. You can continue to follow this issue:[The MAUI Blazor doesn't work on iOS 16.2.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12124)